# How to include different templates conditionally?

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I have a base template an I need include different footers for frontend and backend. Is this possible in Symfony 4?

I need the following include for frontend pages:

```
{% include ('core/footer-frontend.html.twig') %}
```

and for the backend

```
{% include ('core/footer-backend.html.twig') %}
```

How do I tell the base template which footer to include?

Comment: What do you consider frontend and backend?  Do you want to do it based on a url parameter, the user role..?

Comment: In my app backend have in route /admin or controller from with I call template are in src/controller/admin

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you ask how to do it in Twig or overall in controller + twig, but for Twig you can simply do:

```
{% if conditionIfThisIsFrontend %}
    {% include ('core/footer-frontend.html.twig') %}
{% else %}
    {% include ('core/footer-backend.html.twig') %}
{% endif %}
```

Obviously you need to fill in `conditionIfThisIsFrontend` by setting this variable inside controller to hold `true` if this is rendered in frontend context or `false` for backend context.

Comment: but tis way suppose that i setting variable in every admin controller or may i have set for every admin controller in once?

Comment: It depends how your controllers code look like. If you have some basic admin controller you can set variable holding that value there and use it in every other admin controllers that extends that controller.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is to make your base template, then make a frontend and a backend template that each extend your base template. The main code can go into base, the frontend/backend templates can extend the base and include the correct footer. When you work on the backend views, extend the backend template, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it based on the uri, you can access the current route via the `app` [global variable](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#app) and then match it against your admin url using a [comparison operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#comparisons):

```
{% if app.request.pathinfo starts with '/admin/' %}
    {% include ('core/footer-backend.html.twig') %}
{% else %}
    {% include ('core/footer-frontend.html.twig') %}
{% endif %}
```

You might want to add an additional safeguard to the condition like `and is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')` to ensure that no route leaks if an error page is shown.